# Partition with identical items on certain days?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

On a Friday morning, the fruit shop has $14$
identical bags of apples. If they all sold by Sunday night and we
are interested in how many bags were sold on each day.

(a) How many different ways could the bags of apples have been sold on
Partition with identical items
Friday, Saturday and Sunday? $0$ bags can be sold on any day.

(b) How many different ways could the bags of apples have been sold on
Friday, Saturday and Sunday given that at least two of the bags were
sold on each of the three days?

For this problem I know ones uses the formula

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        n \\
        r  \\ 
        \end{pmatrix}=  \begin{pmatrix}
        n-1 \\
        r  \\ 
        \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
        n-1 \\
        r-1  \\ 
        \end{pmatrix}  \
$$

What I am confused about this problem is first how one applies this formula? 
According to the information we can says that

$n = 14, r=3$.

We then substitute and

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        n \\
        r  \\ 
        \end{pmatrix}=  \begin{pmatrix}
        14-1 \\
        3 \\ 
        \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
        14-1 \\
        3-1  \\  
        \end{pmatrix}  \
= \frac{13!}{3!*(13-1)!} + \frac{13!}{2!*(13-1)!} =8.7
$$

yet I am apprehensive if this is actually the correct way to get the correct answer. Any suggestion on how to solve this would be informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that we represent the $14$ bags as a line of $14$ asterisks (‘stars’):

$$**************$$

Then we insert $2$ bars. Suppose that $a$ bags were sold on Friday, $b$ on Saturday, and $c$ on Sunday. We can put a bar after the first $a$ stars, so that those stars represent the bags sold on Friday. We can put another bar after the first $a+b$ bags (and therefore before the last $c$ bags); the stars between the two bars represent the bags sold on Saturday, and those after the second bar represent the bags sold on Sunday. For instance, if $2$ bags were sold on Friday, $8$ on Saturday, and the remaining $4$ on Sunday, our picture would look like this :

$$**|********\,|****$$

Every possible way of selling the $14$ bags in $3$ days corresponds to a picture like this with $14$ stars and $2$ bars, and each such picture corresponds to a unique breakdown of the sales of the $14$ bags across the $3$ days. There are therefore as many possible ways in which the $14$ bags could have been sold as there are strings of $14$ stars and $2$ bars.

Those are strings of $14+2=16$ symbols, exactly $2$ of which are bars, There are $\binom{16}2$ different ways to choose which $2$ of the $16$ are to be bars, so there are $\binom{16}2=120$ different strings of $14$ stars and $2$ bars and hence $120$ different ways in which sales of the $14$ bags could have been distributed across the $3$ days.

For the second part of the problem, we can simply set aside $6$ of the $14$ stars: those represent the minimum of $2$ bags sold on each of $3$ days. The real question is in how many ways the remaining $14-6=8$ bags could have been sold over the $3$ days in question. That’s a problem just like the first one, but with fewer bags; see if you can work it out on your own.

You may want to read [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)); it’s actually fairly decent.